# Adding Speech to Text feature in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I need to add Speech to text feature in RASA, where user can ask questionsusing his voice and bot will answer him by chat. Does anyone know how can I do it in RASA?
As my front-end will be an Android Application. Kindly do tell me how to do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can build a voice bot with Rasa Open Source as long as you use a Speech to Text (STT) API, since Rasa will only process text. This would involve building a custom channel that takes the voice as input, sends it to a STT API and returns the text to Rasa.

You can find some detailed examples on the Rasa blog:

- https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-mozilla-tools/
- https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-mobile-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-aimybox/

If you don't mind using something closed source, integrating the Google Speech API is also an option.